# How do you view new sequence ownership information in Postgres after using ALTER SEQUENCE?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I'm using "ALTER SEQUENCE sequence OWNED BY table.column" to change sequence association in Postgres.  Is there a way to view this new information using \ds or something similar?  \ds still shows the table owner as the sequence owner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OWNED BY table.column` changes the associated column; `OWNER TO newowner` changes the role which owns the sequence. The owner role is what is displayed in `\ds`. I don't know a `psql` command to see the linked column of a sequence. OWNED BY is primary used to cascade a delete of the associated sequence when the referent column is removed.

You can get visibility into the owned by column by constructing a query against the system catalog tables [pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html), [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html), and [pg_attribute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html).  I'm not sure of all the exact semantics of pg_depend, but this query should show you a sequence's column dependency:

```
select tab.relname as tabname, attr.attname as column
from pg_class as seq
join pg_depend as dep on (seq.relfilenode = dep.objid)
join pg_class as tab on (dep.refobjid = tab.relfilenode)
join pg_attribute as attr on (attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid and attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid)
where seq.relname = 'sequence';
```

Comment: this query is not 100% correct - there should be appended a constraint - `dep.classid = 1259`

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT c.relname,u.usename 
  FROM pg_class c, pg_user u
 WHERE c.relowner = u.usesysid and c.relkind = 'S'
   AND relnamespace IN (
                        SELECT oid
                          FROM pg_namespace
                         WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
                           AND nspname != 'information_schema'
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuri Levinsky's answer modified to include the namespace column:

```
SELECT n.nspname, c.relname, u.usename
FROM pg_class c
INNER JOIN pg_user u ON c.relowner = u.usesysid
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE c.relkind = 'S'
  AND n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
  AND n.nspname != 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you also be able to change the owner on the sequences to zeus_eucus where the owner is postgres ? Otherwise I’m unable to modify them.

--list all the database sequences:

SELECT * FROM pg_sequences;

--Changing sequenceowner of a sequence:

$  ALTER SEQUENCE <schema_name>.<sequence_name> OWNERTO <new_name>;

Comment: `pg_sequences` does not exist on older postgresql.